# Understanding the definition of the $ACC$ condition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

My professor gave us the following definition:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. $R$ has the ascending chain condition $(ACC)$ if, for every ascending chain of ideals $$I_{1} \subset I_{2} \subset I_{3} \subset ...$$ in $R,$ there is an $N > 0$ so that $I_{n} = I_{n+1}$ for $n \geq N.$

**My question is:**

Does that condition means they are equal up to associates? i.e. $I_{n} = u I_{n+1}$ for some unit $u \in R^{\times}$

If that is correct, can anyone show me a rigor proof to that please?

Comment: It is not normally a thing to talk about "associate ideals" in the sense of them being unit multiples of each other. It is not a meaningful thing for ideals anyway.  It is useful for elements because $x=uy$ implies $(x)=(y)$ as ideals (in a commutative ring anyhow.))

Comment: yeah I am actually using this information in a polynomial ring in one unknown $B[t]$ where $B$ is an integral domain satisfying the $ACC$ condition ...... I want to use that property on the leading coefficients of my polynomials as I know that $B$ satisfies $ACC.$@rschwieb ..... Does this property provable for leading coefficients ? if so how?

Comment: Is it iff the last statement in your first comment?@rschwieb

Comment: @Math As a note on proper terminology: the object which you call a polynomial unknown should be referred to under the correct name of *indeterminate*. There is nothing unknown about it, but it is indeed indeterminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the equation $I_n = I_{n+1}$ means, i.e. what it is *defined* to mean, is equality of sets; in other words, it means that $x \in I_n$ if and only if $x \in I_{n+1}$.

On the other hand, if $u$ is a unit, then you should be able to check that $I_{n+1} = u I_{n+1}$, which means that $x \in I_{n+1}$ if and only if $x \in u I_{n+1}$. (Hint on the proof: $x = u (u^{-1} x)$).

Therefore, $I_n = I_{n+1}$ is equivalent to $I_n = uI_{n+1}$ for some unit $u \in R^{\times}$.

Comment: Oops, thank you.